# Can I start my project using MVC, Razor and HTML5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am very new in web application and I want to implement MVC pattern for my new work. Is it advisable to use the combination of MVC 4, Razor and HTML5?

Comment: search on the google your question do not show any efforts for what you want first try to know what you want? do your project really need a mvc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you can use any technology, but according to me MVC4 is the thing you really want to work with.

Razor Engine is light weight than aspx pages.

With HTML5, build the pages compatible for all browsers.

MVC4 is the architecture where you can create wonders.

This is an awesome combination you can go for.

To get started, Go for Visual Studio 2012/13.

Here are the links which are very helpful:

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v

Answer (score 0):

The Razor syntax is based on the C# programming language, and that's the language that's used most often with ASP.NET Web Pages. It is quite fast.

HTML5 is the way to go if you want to build cross platform web pages. Plus HTML5 is picking up fast with lots of features being added and most of browsers supporting it.

MVC4 platform is one of the most secured architecture you should go for.

This combination is good .